# Understanding the generalised binomial theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, binomial-theorem

In lecture we wrote the following:

> **Generalised Binomial Theorem**: For any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ holds
>
> $$(1+x)^\alpha = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{\alpha}{k} x^k$$
>
> where $x$ is a formal variable ***or*** $x \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\lvert x \rvert \le 1$.

But what is a formal variable? Does that mean that I can, for example, plug in a formal power series $A(z)$ for $x$?

Comment: You can probably just ignore that part.

Comment: It is weird to call it a formal variable and require also that $|x|\leqslant 1$. The series $B_\alpha(x)$ converges for $|x|<1$, and has the property that $B_\alpha'(x) = \alpha B_{\alpha-1}(x)$. When $\alpha$ is a non-negative integer, the series is a polynomial and gives the usual binomial expansion.

Comment: @Pedro: The statements says $x$ is a formal variable OR $x \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\lvert x \rvert \le 1$.

Comment: Then the statement is confusing, unless you tell us what your definition $(1+x)^\alpha$ is (for me, it's the power series you give). If it is $\exp(\alpha \mathrm{log}(1+x))$, perhaps it makes more sense. You can separate it into two statements: (1) $\exp(\alpha \mathrm{log}(1+x))$ is equal to that power series as a formal power series (2) it is equal to it for $|x|<1$. I guess you can also define it as the unique solution to $(1+x)f' = \alpha  f$ with $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @Pedro I believe this confusion is what the question is about.

Comment: Think of a formal variable as a letter that you don't evaluate as a constant, just some squiggle. You can write several of those next to each other and some constant, that's multiplication. You can join those monomials with plus signs without evaluating, that's addition. Now you have series (and polynomials). Then define how to do arithmetic on series. Then what series you can plug into others. E.g. your $A(z)$ must have a zero constant term, i.e. $A(0)=0$. Convergence is defined differently, too, but in a way that relates to how it's defined in analysis. Etc. etc.